# Systemd networking.service returns "(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)" on ExecStartPre code

Tags: 16.04, networking, services, systemd

Looking at the 'status' of networking.service in Ubuntu 16.04.4 it shows that "ExecStartPre" fails:

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
       └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf

Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-04-10 00:47:02 EDT; 11h ago

Docs: man:interfaces(5)

Process: 735 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, 
       status=0/SUCCESS)

Process: 731 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] 
       && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] 
       && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Main PID: 735 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service
```

**The issue in question is in the code failure:**

```
 Process: 731 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] 
       && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] 
       && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Upon digging into how the networking.services script is setup, I found that it is uses a file to set the environment for "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" in EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/networking:

```
# Configuration for networking init script being run during
# the boot sequence

# Set to 'no' to skip interfaces configuration on boot
#CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=yes
```

However, this is disabled (commented out), then running the script's command manually:

```
 $ sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ]
```

Produces the output:

: 1: [: missing ]

I also get the same result if I set environment to "yes" with

```
 export CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=yes
```

yes: 1: [: missing ]

I'm not sure what exactly the result of this line of code is supposed to produce exactly to have a successful execution. Thanks in advance to anyone that answers how to correct this, or if it's something that can be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For details on the `(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)` status of the `ExecStartPre=` of networking.service, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435190/281844.

For the record, this was filed with Debian on https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=894759 and I sent them a patch to fix it, so it might end up making its way all the way to Ubuntu and eventually get fixed :-)

Regarding your tests trying to emulate the command, you need single quotes there (even though the systemd output doesn't show them there.)

This would be correct:

```
sh -c '[ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ]'
```

You can also see the contents of file `/lib/systemd/system/networking.service` on your system, or also output of command `systemctl cat networking.service` for the exact `ExecStartPre=` command in use by that unit.

Comment: Tried your fix in the bug report, works fine no errors using

     /bin/sh -c 'if [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ]; then udevadm settle; fi'